# Change background image with click on button (using jQuery and API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, background-image

I am using an API that returns an random URL to a random image and set that to the background-image of the body. How can I make that to change after every click of a button? I have the code below, but that doesnt work.

```
function changeImage() {

          $.getJSON("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=336b527b2e18d045045820b78062b95c825376311326b2a08f9b93eef7efc07b", function(result){

           var randomPhoto = result.urls.full;

      console.log(randomPhoto);

      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(randomPhoto)');

      });


   };
```

I use a jQuery click event on the button to call the function.

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {


    changeImage();


    });

});
```

function loads a new JSON object with image every time, but the background-image doesnt change...

Comment: You are actually changing the background-color to a string 'url(randomPhoto'. You should try taking out the quotes.

Comment: do this - $('body').css('background-image', ''url(' +randomPhoto+ ')');

Answer (score 1):

As DynoMyte suggested, you should do this instead:

```
function changeImage() {
    var src = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=336b527b2e18d045045820b78062b95c825376311326b2a08f9b93eef7efc07b";
    $.getJSON(src, function(result){
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ result.urls.full +')');

    });
};
```

Comment: thanks everyone!!. What do the + signs actually do? The problem I now have is that it sets the background only once. Here is the codepen (work in progress). Is it just caching? http://codepen.io/chemok78/pen/Rarora/?editors=1010

Comment: the `+` signs serve to concatenate strings, as anything plus a string is a string. we need to evaluate `result.urls.full`, a string property of an object, in order to pass the data contained (the full string url) into `css()`.

Comment: btw, if you have a caching-ish issue, you can remove the current bg before adding a new one: `$(body).css('background-image', '');`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(randomPhoto)');
```

To this:

```
 $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+randomPhoto+')');
```